# How do I cancel out identical part of two audio files in Wavepad? (probably using phase difference?)

Tags: audio, mp3, aac

Let's say I have two similar audio files in different format (such as MP3 and AAC) from the same master (CD audio or WAV file) and I want to find some differences of quality between the two files. (to examine their quality change and compression techniques)

I did some research on it and figured out a way that I can overlay the two wave shapes (or spectrogram pattern) and cancel out the identical part so that the leftover can demonstrate the better effectiveness of one of the formats.

Can Wavepad from NCH Software actually do that kind of function? It is the only audio software I found that can open AAC files (Reaper and Audacity can't) so I hope it would contain a function like that, but since I am a newbie on this, I have no idea how to actually overlay the two files and delete identical parts. I also searched the Wavepad wiki but no idea.

Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Many audio apps can do this, so long as they can handle more than one track at once.
The working method is...

1. Open both files into separate tracks
2. Make the both the same volume - this can be difficult or impossible depending on whether additional audio compression was used on either source.
3. Shuffle the start positions until you line them both up to sample accuracy - this can either be time-consuming or impossible, depending on whether your files are actually time-aligned & coherent for their entire duration.
4. Invert the phase of one of your tracks.
   At this point you can make additional tweaks by ear for points 2 & 3. You are aiming for 'maximum silence'.
5. Mix, bounce, or export the resulting sound. This is your 'difference'.

Your chances in all this are improved if you made all the comparison files yourself, from a single original WAV or AIFF.

Comment: I converted an original WAV file into MP3 and AAC using Switch converter from NCH software, so I'm good to go. However, I don't understand why you mean in process 3. Do you mean I need to make the starting point of the two audio files equal to 0:00? And what do you also mean in making additional tweaks by ear for points 2 & 3?

Comment: and I tried inverting one of the audio and combined them together, but of course, the tracks won't show the difference because the two audio are still being merged and creating even a larger wave shape. How can I eliminate the identical part?

Comment: You need the files sample-aligned or it won't work. You cannot rely on the actual file start point to be that accurate, so you will need to move one against the other & match. You eliminate the identical part by phase-inverting one of the audio tracks. You'll have to look up the manual for how. If it gets louder, you didn't invert the phase [or you inverted both]

Comment: oh.. is phase inverting different from normally inverting?

Comment: I've no idea what you would consider to be "normally inverting".

Comment: There is an 'inverting' function in Audacity. I'm not sure about this, but when I opened the WAV and MP3 version of audio (almost identical I guess..?) in audacity and inverted one of them and merged the two, the audio is not canceling.. I'm not sure if the 'invert' function in audacity is actually doing a phase invert..

Comment: https://manual.audacityteam.org/man/invert.html says that's phase-inverting. if it doesn't cancel, you weren't time-aligned.

Comment: Sorry for this, but I still cannot understand what time-aligning means. Do the two audio need to be started at a different time period? Since when I combine audio A and B, it will produce the subset of A and B, still containing the intersection that I want to get rid of.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/93804/discussion-between-felix-lee-and-tetsujin).

Comment: No,. let's not. You need to do some more research. We established in your earlier questions that you are trying to re-invent the wheel. This research has been done & the results published long ago. No-one on stack exchange can help you by teaching you every little step in how to process audio. You need to do that on your own.